# How many 4 vertices connective graphs not including a triangle?

Tags: graph-theory

How many 4 vertices connective graphs not including a triangle?

I am thinking the answer might be 2, for one is a square, another is straight. But I am not sure.

Comment: What about the graph $G=(V,E)$ with $E=\{(1,2),(2,3),(2,4)\}$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean simple graphs, i.e., graphs with no loops or multiple edges. Every tree on $4$ vertices satisfies your condition, because a tree has no cycles at all, and you’ve missed the tree with a vertex of degree $3$. If the graph is not a tree, it must contain a cycle, that cycle must be a $4$-cycle, and it’s easy to check that adding any edge to a $4$-cycle creates a triangle. Thus, the graphs are the $4$-cycle and the trees on $4$ vertices.

Comment: Actually, since the graph can't have odd cycles greater than 3, aren't the set of graphs we're looking for just the set of bipartite graphs?

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, they are, though I don’t know that that makes them any easier to identify.

Comment: I guess that's fair, though the description sounds shorter.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So is there an easy way to tell how many these graphs are there?

Comment: @James: In general? I don’t know for sure, but I suspect not. Here the problem is manageable precisely because the number of vertices is small.